# Show relative pathnames of files edited in the last git commit?

Tags: git, relative-path

In working with Git, I'm usually (quite often) editing the same file or group of files several times in a row.

To make it easier to open the files edited in the last commit, I wrote an alias:

```
alias vig='vim $(git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD)'
```

This works perfectly, except for two cases:

1. If [the filenames contain whitespace or special characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)—I'm not worried about this because my source code files don't, and my directory names in my projects don't;
2. **If I'm in a subdirectory rather than the top directory of my project,** the names reported by `git diff --names-only` are relative to the wrong directory.

How can I make Git show these pathnames relative to the current directory?

Comment: Consider adding `--relative`. This does not solve the first problem, but for that you need `-z` and `xargs -0` or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

My new `vig` alias is:

```
alias vig='vim $(git log -1 --name-only --relative --pretty= .)'
```

This still doesn't handle whitespace in filenames, but for my purposes this is fine.

This is a little bit different in functionality than my earlier version: rather than opening the files edited in the most recent commit, it opens the files *in the current subtree* that were most recently edited.  Which I expect will be even handier.